# jQuery: Animate Removal of Style Attribute from Multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have ~33 divs that I am setting the position of randomly and animating this places. These divs are originally positioned with the help of `flex` and then the positions are randomized by setting their positions to `relative` and changing the `left` and `top` values. This happens every click.

On every alternate click, I want to return the divs to their normal position. So far the only solution to this I've found is the `.removeAttr('style')` method. However, I want to be able to animate their return to original position. Is this possible?

Here is the code:

```
var position_checker = false;
$(document).click(function() {
 if(position_checker == false) {
  $('.poster05-text').each(function() {
  var position = $(this).offset();

  $(this).css({
    position: 'relative',
  }, position);

  var docHeight = $(document).height(),
    docWidth = $(document).width(),
    divWidth = 500,
    divHeight = 500,
    heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
    widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;

    var posLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * widthMax);
    var posTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * heightMax);

    // console.log(docHeight, docWidth);

  $(this).animate({
    position: 'fixed',
    left: posLeft,
    top: posTop
  }, 1000 , 'easeInQuint'); 
});
  position_checker=true;
}
else if(position_checker==true) {
$('.poster05-text').each(function() {
$(this).removeAttr('style');
});
position_checker=false;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know this a right way to do that or not .. but anyway .. you need to save the previous `left` and `top` positions for each div on array

```
var position_checker = false , T_L_Positions = [];
$(document).click(function() {
 if(position_checker == false) {
  $('.poster05-text').each(function(i) {
  var position = $(this).offset();

  $(this).css({
    position: 'relative',
  }, position);

  T_L_Positions[i] = new Array(position.top ,position.left);

  var docHeight = $(document).height(),
    docWidth = $(document).width(),
    divWidth = 500,
    divHeight = 500,
    heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
    widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;

    var posLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * widthMax);
    var posTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * heightMax);

    // console.log(docHeight, docWidth);

  $(this).animate({
    position: 'fixed',
    left: posLeft,
    top: posTop
  }, 1000 , 'easeInQuint'); 
});
  position_checker=true;
 }
  else if(position_checker==true) {
   $('.poster05-text').each(function(i) {
      $(this).animate({
         position: 'relative',
         left: T_L_Positions[i][1],
         top: T_L_Positions[i][0]
      }, 1000 , 'easeInQuint'); 
   });
position_checker=false;
 }
});
```

**Note:** **This Code Not Tested** .. but you can try it

maybe you'll need to wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function(){ //code here })`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, while it's an intelligent solution, the divs don't return to the same position as they were in the `flex` box. They return the the position with tons of extra space in them.

Comment: Look @ShivamSinha you provide just the js code .. so my code is to give you the idea of how you can get the top , left position and save it on the array then return it back .. if this idea work the rest is on you .. I don't know the purpose of `position : relative` in your code.. you only know .. so you can cut/paste the line of the array before change the css to relative .. and you can keep working with animation styles to reach the effect you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a non-JS solution. You should be able to use CSS Transitions to do this.

```
transition: top 500ms, left 300ms;
```

That way you can just set and remove the position and let CSS deal with the animation.

For more information check out these examples:

- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp
- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately since the `top` and `left` values are being added via JS and aren't originally in the CSS, the transition property doesn't work.